# if $2f(x)+f''(x)=-xf'(x)$ show that $f(x)$and $f'(x)$ are bounded on $R$

Tags: analysis

**Assume that $f$ is twice diffentiable on $R$,and such**

> $$2f(x)+f''(x)=-xf'(x)$$

**show that:**

> $f(x)$and $f'(x)$  are bounded on $R$

My try:since
$$2f(x)+f''(x)+xf'(x)=0$$
and following I can't any work,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define
$$g=f^2+\frac{1}{2}(f')^2.$$
By definition, $g$ is non-negative and differentiable; moreover,
$$g'(x)=f'(x)\cdot\left(2f(x)+f''(x)\right)=-x\cdot (f'(x))^2,\quad\forall x\in \Bbb R.$$
Therefore, $g$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$, so $g(\Bbb R)\subset [0, g(0)]$. The conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you,Then How prove $f(x)$ is bounded on $R$,and $f'(x)$

Comment: @nanchangjian: We have shown that $f^2+\frac{1}{2}(f')^2\le g(0)$ on $\Bbb R$. Starting from this, can you see both $f$ and $f'$ are bounded by yourself?